# What angle does the incident ray from point A on the ground make with the ground so reflected ray off curved mirror reaches the eye above the ground?

Tags: reflection, geometric-optics

[image]

In this illustration:

- E is the eye of the observer, projecting E straight to the ground gives E'.
- A is a red dot on the ground.
- P is the point of incidence on the mirror. P' is the projection of P on the ground.
- AE makes an angle α (angle EAE') with the ground.
- The incident ray AP makes an angle β with the ground (angle PAP').
- Thinking of the mirror ball as a globe-like object, the circle on the ground whose center is O is the projection of the "latitude" of the ball that goes through P, and that projection goes through P'.

Here are my questions:

- Is it possible to know angle β? Is it possible that β equals α?
- Does line OP' bisect angle AP'E'?

Here is another illustration, with circle O simply being the bottom of the cylinder. The same questions for this case.
[image]

Comment: @ProfRob I'm not a physics major, nor am I doing this as homework for school. This is a only problem I need to understand in order to have a good mindset so I can draw convincing reflections in my art. So I have no idea where to start, let alone solve it. What makes a question a homework-type anyway?

Comment: I agree, upon reflection(!), that this looks quite unlikely to be a homework problem and I have removed my close vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]
[image]

May be above two Figures answer a part of your questions.

Note : double-clicking on the images you'll have larger and more clear views.

Comment: May I ask what program did you use to create these images? GeoGebra?

Comment: @Vun-Hugh Vaw : Yes, precisely , GeoGebra.

Comment: Hmm, have you actually tried watching these pictures via red-blue glasses? The cyan counterparts of $AP$ and $AP'$ are missing, which leads to left-eye image lacking these lines, and thus the stereogram is quite hard to comprehend.

Comment: @Ruslan : You are right. I knew it from the beginning. I'll try to correct it asap or delete the 3Ds. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

**1)  "Is it possible to know angle β?"**

Yes, in principle, but very it's very complicated.  There are two answers, so far, for your two dimensional version of this question here

[Given a specific incident ray and a specific reflected ray, how to find the exact point of incidence on a circular convex mirror?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/646974/given-a-specific-incident-ray-and-a-specific-reflected-ray-how-to-find-the-exac)

for someone to find a method, they would need to know the radius of the sphere or cylinder, the positions of $A$ and $E$ and they might need to do it in terms of an angle $\gamma$, angle $OAP'$

**2) "Is it possible that β equals α?"**

Sphere: Yes

Reason: Imagine we increase the height of $E$, $\alpha$ could be very high, but $\beta$ can't go higher than the angle to the top of the sphere.   So for a high $E$, $\alpha \gt \beta$.
If $E$ was very low, $\alpha$ would be low, but $\beta$ can't be too low, the reflected ray would be reflected into the ground too early.  So for a low $E$, $\beta \gt \alpha$.

Therefore it must be possible to find a height for $E$ where $\alpha = \beta$, although in general they would not be equal.

Cylinder:  No

Reason: $AE$ is shorter than $APE$, but both paths would have to do the same change in height so $\alpha \gt \beta$, always, in this case.

**3) "Does line OP' bisect angle AP'E'?"**

Cylinder: Yes

Reason: If we changed the height of $E$, the height of $P$ would have to vary, but it would still be above $P'$, so it's like replacing the cylinder with a plane mirror.

Sphere:  No

Reason: The above would not be true for a sphere and the position of $P'$ would change, so in general the angle bisection wouldn't occur, although there would be certain positions for $E$ where it could occur.